# About likelihood ratio computation

Tags: computational-physics

My head is stuck into a rather simple problem I don't know why. I'll explain:
1- bosons have an angular distribution in $\theta$ and $\phi$:

$$F(\theta, \phi) = \frac{3}{4\pi}[0.5(1-\alpha) + (0.5)(3\alpha-1)cos(\theta)^2 - \beta sin(\theta)^2cos(2\phi)- \sqrt2\gamma sin(2\theta)cos(\phi)] $$
With $\alpha=0.65, \beta=0.06, \gamma=-0.18$

I sample some Monte Carlo events from this distribution (50000).
Now 0- bosons are uniformly distributed $\theta, \phi$ that means that the pdf is a constant:
$$f(\theta, \phi) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \quad if \quad \theta \in [0,\pi], \phi \in [0, 2\pi]$$

I'm asked to test the hypothesis that the Montecarlo data comes from 1- or 0- distribution. This sounds really trivial of course. I opted for a simple likelihood ratio. Note now that $F(\theta, \phi)$ reduces to uniform when $\alpha = \alpha_0 =  1./3, \beta = \beta_0= 0, \gamma = \gamma_0=  0$:
$$\lambda = \frac{\prod f(\theta, \phi|\alpha_0, \beta_0, \gamma_0)}{\prod F(\theta, \phi|\alpha, \beta, \gamma)} $$

So basically what I do now is simple taking every $\theta$ and $\phi$ in my 50000 events and plug it into each pdf and get the value or the likelihood for that instance to be sampled given the uniform or alternative hypothesis. Since both are, by definition of pdf < 1 then this multiplication computation exceeds the numerical precision of a long double in c++. What I did then is turn into a logarithm:
$$log(\lambda) =  \sum log(f(\theta_i, \phi_i | \alpha_0, \beta_0, \gamma_0)) - \sum log(F(\theta_i, \phi_i | \alpha, \beta, \gamma)) $$

This value turns out to be:
$$log(\lambda) = -40051  \rightarrow \lambda = e^{-40051}$$ 
with the method I used before.

I expected a really small value for the statistics since a sample from one of the hypothesis I'm testing on but can it be this small? thank you everyone in advance. Have a nice day.

Giacomo